# Could not find class QWebElement

Tags: java, qt, javadoc, qt-jambi

I'm using QtWebkit to develop a webapplication framework. Now I've begun to ude the DOM and I tryed to use the QWebElement. But when I tried to compile it brought the following error:

symbol  : class QWebElement
location: class test
        QWebElement elem = new QWebElement();

Here is an example that doesn't work:

```
import com.trolltech.qt.gui.*;
import com.trolltech.qt.webkit.*;
import com.trolltech.qt.core.*;
import com.trolltech.qt.xml.*;

public class test {
    public test() {
        QWebElement elem = new QWebElement();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QApplication.initialize(args);
        new test();
        QApplication.exec();
    }
}
```

Could anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:
I forgot:
When I look in the javadoc, I cant find it! everything says that it doesn't exist. But I've seen other people using it.
Does it exist or not?

Comment: What version of Qt do you have?

Comment: What version of QtJambi do you have? downloaded from where?  if you use 'jar -tvf qtjambi.jar' can you see the QWebElement.class file in there ?  QtJambi is future!  JavaScript so-so!

Comment: I'm using QtJambi 4.7 and the same Qt and I'm downloading it here: http://qt-jambi.org/downloads